# How to store multiple values for a key in a TRIE structure?

Tags: arrays, list, dart, data-structures, hashmap

So I am still in the theory portion of my project (a phonebook) and am wondering how to store multiple values for a single key in a TRIE structure. When I looked it up most people said when creating a phone book use a TRIE: but if I wanted to store number, email, address, etc all under the key - which would be the name - how would that work? Could I still use a TRIE? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way? Thanks.

Comment: Store a type with fields `number`, `email`, `address`, etc. Each value in the trie is an instance of this type.

Comment: Please share the basic structure of your trie. People might suggest you based on your current work.

Comment: I am in the theory stage of my project right now so I guess I am looking for the structure. I want to have it so I can store (name = john, number = 878392743, email = null, address = null) etc. I think a dictionary would be good for this but since it is a phonebook I continue to see TRIE structures.

Answer (score 0):

I think usually you would create separate indexes for each dimension (i.e. phone number, name, ...). These would normally be B-trees or Hashmaps.
Generally, these individual indexes will allow faster lookup than a multi-dimensional index (even though multidimensional TRIEs have very fast look up speed).

If you really want to use a multi-dimensional try, have a look at the [PH-Tree](http://phtree.org), it is a true multi-dimensional TRIE (disclaimer: I am self-advertising here).
There are Java and C++ implementations, but they are all aimed at 64bit numbers, e.g. coordinates in space. WARNING: The available implementations allow only one entry per key, so you will have to store Lists for each key in order to allow multiple entries per key.

If you want to use the PH-Tree for strings etc (I would treat the phone number as a string): you can either write your own PH-Tree (*not* easy to do) or encode the strings in a magic number. For example, convert the leading six characters into numbers by using their ASCII code and create a small hash of the whole string and store the hash in the remaining two bytes. There are many ways to improve this number. This number can then be used as one dimension of the key.

Conceptually, the PH-Tree interleaves the bits of all dimensions into a single long bitstring. These long bit-strings are then stored in a TRIE, however there are some quirks (i.e. each node has up to 2^dimension children). For a full explanation, please have a look at the papers on the website.

In summary: I would not use a multi-dimensional index unless you really need it. If you need to use a multi-dimensional index, the PH-Tree may be a good choice, it is very fast to update and scales comparatively well with increasing dimensionality.